# Deduct 1hr from Current Time (Strange behavior)

Tags: c, linux

The answer to the main question is already out there, but I am facing a strange issue with strftime. Check the following code

```
int lookback = 60;
time_t ct;
time(&ct);
ct -= (lookback*60);
struct tm *ts = localtime(&ct);

char path[1024];
char format[512] = "/home/stash/%Y%m%d";

printlog("Maximum Lookback time: %02d-%02d-%d %2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d", ts->tm_mday, ts->tm_mon+1, ts->tm_year+1900, ts->tm_hour, ts->tm_min, ts->tm_sec); // This one works just fine

strftime(path, 1024, format, ts); // But strftime gives me current time
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong maybe? Or is there any other way I can achieve this? Note, I need to use strftime since the format is a dynamic var which will be changed externally.

Edited

Comment: Why are you using double percentages in the format string? The percentage character is not special in string literals and need not be escaped.

Comment: Also, the `strftime` format is for dates (if you remove the extra percentage characters), so how do you notice the "time"? *If* there was a problem it would only be noticeable around midnight.

Comment: Ignore the double percentage, when I wrote it I made a mistake, corrected it. But yes.. I have checked it after midnight.. but there are other ways.. I checked it too.. why dont you try and let me know if you have the same behavior.

Comment: Works fine for me once I add the time into the format string.

Comment: Using a format to show *the time*, [I can't reproduce your problem](http://ideone.com/7VVQ9u), you must be doing something which you do not show us if you have a problem.

Comment: yes, its seems that the printlog function for some reason was modifying the timestamp which is very weird.. anyways.. thanks guys for the help

Comment: To avoid this sort of error you can do `struct tm ts = *localtime(&ct);`  (and change `->` to `.` later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are running into the problem that `localtime()` returns a pointer to static storage, so multiple calls to `localtime()` end up all pointing at the same data.  In particular, it means that if you call `localtime()` twice with two different values for the time, and then analyze the output, the output appears to be the same.

Look at this adaptation of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int lookback = 60;
    time_t c0 = time(0);
    time_t ct = c0 - (lookback*60);
    struct tm *t0 = localtime(&c0);
    //struct tm  copy_t0 = *t0;
    struct tm *ts = localtime(&ct);

    char path[1024];
    char p0[1024];
    char format[512] = "/home/stash/%Y%m%d-%H%M%S";
    strftime(p0, sizeof(p0), format, t0);
    //strftime(p0, sizeof(p0), format, &copy_t0);
    strftime(path, sizeof(path), format, ts); 
    printf("%lu: %s\n", (unsigned long)c0, p0);
    printf("%lu: %s\n", (unsigned long)ct, path);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run that code, I get sample output:

```
1451456585: /home/stash/20151229-212305
1451452985: /home/stash/20151229-212305
```

When I use the commented out code — which makes a copy of the structure from `localtime()` — then I get the answer I wanted in the first place:

```
1451456732: /home/stash/20151229-222532
1451453132: /home/stash/20151229-212532
```

Obviously, another way to handle the difference would be to call `localtime()` and then `strftime()`, before the next calls to `localtime()` and `strftime()`.

Comment: thanks.. made the changes and now its working fine